# How to change a control's appearance based on whether its (dynamic) context menu has items, using a reusable Style?

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-style

I have a button with a dynamic context menu (i.e. fed from an ItemsSource). I would like to use its `ContextMenu`'s `.HasItems` property as a trigger to disable it when the context menu is empty. The following does not seem to work, even though the debugger shows no issues with the binding:

```
<Style x:Key="ContextMenuButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Path=ContextMenu.HasItems}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Used like this:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource ContextMenuButtonStyle}" Content="Items" Click="ShowContext">
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" Placement="Top" VerticalOffset="-1" />
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

This always just behaves as if there were no items, i.e. the button stays disabled. However, if I comment out that trigger I can immediately see that the context menu clearly contains items at that point.

Interestingly, I have a second, similar trigger, based on `ContextMenu.IsOpen` that is working fine:

```
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Path=ContextMenu.IsOpen}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
        </DataTrigger>
```

So maybe the issue isn't actually the binding in the trigger but the querying/updating of the `ItemsSource` that is somehow impacted by the disabled state? Any other ideas or hints on how to resolve this?

**Update**: I have by now found out that the `Items` collection is apparently not populated from `ItemsSource` until the context menu is actually shown, so that certainly explains why my `HasItems` approach doesn't work. So, is there maybe a way to have the trigger react to the contents of the referenced `ItemsSource` - but without explicitly referencing that source in the Style so that it could be reused for other buttons with different items sources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I just realised the obvious answer as I was posting my update to the question:

```
<Style x:Key="ContextMenuButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Path=ContextMenu.ItemsSource.Count}" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about doing this instead?

```
<Style x:Key="ContextMenuButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=MyItems.Count}" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: in principle, yes, this is similar to what I started out with. However, my current goal is to make the style reusable and thus independent of the specific `ItemsSource`.